# Do I overclock my RPi without voiding my warranty using RASpi-Config?

Tags: overclocking

I want to overclock my Pi to improve performance, while still not sacrificing the warranty. Yes they're cheap, but I still want to preserve the warranty. I have seen blog posts on RPi's website about a new "turbo mode," but yet I haven't quite found out how to do that. I have seen in a few places that to use `raspi-config` utility to configure the turbo mode.

So when I open the utility, it warns me about the risk of overclocking. If this was meant to be a way to overclock safely, then why all the warnings? And then when I launch it, there is only one labeled "turbo mode." It seems very confusing that they would do this.

**So how do I do it without voiding my warranty?** Also, when configuring it, is if it boots up or not a good indication of if it goes too high, or should I also perform some kind of test to ensure that it isn't making mistakes?

Comment: @syb0rg Very similar questions, but that doesn't tell ***HOW*** to do it.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Did you read the *entire* answer, including the links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That has changed. **There's a certain set of requirements before the warranty bit is set.**

**In short, its - if any of these parameters are set**

- `force_turbo`
- `current_limit_override`
- `temp_limit`

**AND this parameter is set**

- `over_voltage>0`

That's when the warranty is voided. Otherwise as long as you don't set any of the first three parameters, you should be fine

This thread has more information -> http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=6201&p=206472

Answer (score 1):

there are several parameters you may change when overclocking, the CPU frequency, memory latency, CPU voltage. as long as you change frequencies, you are safe. if you change the voltage, you blow the hardware fuse inside the chip and void your warranty.

to reiterate, DONT change the voltage settings if you want to keep your warranty.